# Don't make functions within a loop. - jslint error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint, jshint

I am getting this jslint error

> Don't make functions within a loop.

I can't change the javascript that is causing this issue - however I cant, due to restrictions from modifying it.

So, I want to turn this validation to check for this error off in a particular javascript file.

Is this possible to do for this js error?

Comment: You say "jslint" in the title but "jshint" in the body of the question. Which is it?

Comment: Why do you HAVE to create the function in the loop? Could you show us the code you're using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that valildation check is not optional.

A possible workaround:

```
// simple closure scoping i to the function.
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (index) {
         console.log(index);
     }(i));
}
// this works, however it's difficult to site read and not a blast to debug
```

A solution:

```
// same exact output
function logger(index) {
    console.log(index);
}

// same output. Minus declaring all vars at the
// top of the function and console this passes jslint.
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    logger(i);
}
```

Comment: But aren't there very valid cases for doing so?  Like closing over the current loop value for creating a bunch of callback functions?

Comment: JSLint isn't the end all be all of javasript. It is a very good guide though. There are cases where even using the most evil of javascript functions, like eval, are needed.