# Adhering to a max length setting with jshint

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jslint, jshint

I see several recommendations for adhering to an 80 character max line length when writing javascript, e.g. Google, npm, Node.js, Crockford. In certain cases, however, I don't see how best to do it. Take the example below

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sampleDatabase', function(err, database) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
  db = database;
});
```

That would throw a jshint warning since it exceeds 80 characters. Now, would you choose to ignore the warning in this instance, or instead opt for a solution such as

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sampleDatabase', 
     function(err, database) {
       if(err) {
         throw err;
       }
      db = database;
     }
 );
```

Comment: Most decent text editors have an option to draw a line on the page at the specified number of characters (it's called different things in each editor). In Notepad++ its under Setting | Editing | Vertical Edge Settings.

Comment: In sublime text you add `"rulers": [80, 100, 120]` to your user prefs. SublimeText also has great jshint plugins (sublimelinter for example).

Comment: Are those rulers not just visual indications to remind you not to run over them? Or do they do something behind-the-scenes?

Comment: No, just visual cues.

Comment: Ah ok, that's not what I'm looking for. JSHint is giving me my cues whenever I run it. I was looking to see how people actually avoid overly long lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can reuse the `url` variable, [Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26422741/1028230) is a great option.  If it's a one shot, as calls like this often are, I'd probably do something like this...

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true, browser: true, maxlen:80 */
/*global MongoClient */

var dbErrHand, db;
dbErrHand = function(err, database) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    db = database;  // Killing me with the global spaghetti!  ;^)
};

MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/sampleDatabase', 
    dbErrHand
);
```

That way, your code is more expressive and you know what db you're connecting to, though Andy just needs to change `var url` to `var mongoSampleDb` or similar to get the same advantage.

I like to pull the functions out so you can visually understand that they're reasonably discrete pieces of logic, even though I realize it isn't over 80 chars here if you put it on its own lines in the `connect` call.  Would think that code is a candidate for reuse in your app as well.

It's also a good general habit to pull out functions so you don't accidentally [make a function inside of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664873/jslint-dont-make-functions-within-a-loop).**[1]**

And, of course, there's a chance that you still end up with insanely long strings, and have to do something like...

```
MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb://whoLetFredNameThisServerBecauseItsTooLong.FredsCompany.com:27017'
        + '/sampleDatabase', 
    dbErrHand
);
```

Good whitespace in nested code exacerbates the problem even more, which might +1 to Andy's idea of setting up variables like this outside of any loops/ifs/nested code.  At some point, it might be worth turning `maxlen` off.

But bracket handling is one of the most subjective decisions there is, especially in JavaScript, where there's no sniff of a great, *a priori* answer. Some bristle like crazy at my parameter-per-line code, or would prefer the `(` was on its own line, like this...

```
MongoClient.connect
(
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/sampleDatabase', 
    dbErrHand
);
```

Surprisingly, JSLint still allows you plenty of room for self-expression!  ;^)

**[1]**  *Nepotistic question link alert, though it was the first one I googled up. Probably an example of Google biasing my results for, um, me.*

Answer (score 1):

I would separate out the url into a new variable.

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sampleDatabase';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database) {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
  db = database;
});
```